# Multi-variable multi-degree inequalities

Tags: inequality, soft-question, math-software

What is the best way to solve inequalities with multiple variables of possibly higher degrees as well? Any method, by hand or software will do.

Want solution similar to this:

$$f(a,b) \geq 0$$
Solution:

$$a \in (-k,k)$$
$$b \in (-a, a)$$

As in, the variables can be dependent on each other (as they will in several situations.)

Edit:

The specific questions I'm trying to solve are:

\begin{align*}
 &1. -\frac{1}{18}((a^2-1)^2 - a^2)p + \frac{1}{18} \geq 0 \text{  and  } -\frac{1}{108}((a^2-1)^2 - a^2)p + \frac{1}{108} \lt 0 \\
&2. -\frac{1}{18}((a^2-1)^2 - a^2)p + \frac{1}{18} \geq 0 \text{  and  }
-\frac{1}{324}a^8p^2 + \frac{1}{54}a^6p^2 - \frac{11}{324}a^4p^2 + \frac{1}{54}a^2p^2 + \frac{1}{324}p^2 + \frac{1}{432} \lt 0\\
\end{align*}
(Two separate questions)

Comment: There is no a general way. What is a concrete problem? Give an example.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg, edited

Comment: Although, there is a method for equalities.